# How can I set OpenFileDialog to accept http:// as well as local files?

Tags: c#, .net, openfiledialog

For a C# Forms app, I want to allow OpenFileDialog to return urls as well as local and network filenames. How can I set it to do that?

```
using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    dlg.Title = FormStrings.Framework_rdlAddFileTitle;
    dlg.CheckFileExists = true;
    dlg.DefaultExt = "rdlx";
    dlg.Filter = @"RDL(X) files|*.rdlx;*.rdl|RDLX files|*.rdlx|RDL files)|*.rdl|All files|*.*";
    dlg.Multiselect = false;
    if (dlg.ShowDialog(GetParentHWnd(doc)) != DialogResult.OK)
        return;
```

Comment: How are you trying to use it? Show your code, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like OpenFileDialog supports it -- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx).

I would create a textbox for the URL that contains the file. Then parse and fetch it in your code.

Comment: I can't find any reference to the http protocol in the link you've provided. In my own testing on this, I've found that the open file dialog will allow browsing to Office 365 directories using the https protocol, but this behavior is inconsistent. It would be nice to get a reference that explicitly dealt with this behavior.

Comment: With arbitrary http sources (e.g. an image file), I've found that it downloads the file to the user's temporary directory and returns the temporary path in the Filename property. I couldn't find a way to enable/disable this or to tell an originally local file from a downloaded remote file apart.